# Allow changing result set size on Careers RSS

Tags: feature-request, jobs, feed

Since Careers doesn't have REST API, it would be nice to add a few parameters to its RSS request query:

1. Number of jobs returned per request. E.g. `size=30`
2. Search by company name. E.g. `company=Qualcomm`
3. Search by job title. E.g. `title=Software Engineer`